# Group array of objects nested by several groupBy functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I try to write a function `groupByMult` using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) that applies several [groupBy](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.0/docs/#groupBy) functions `groupBys` to an array of objects `input`:

```
function groupByMult(groupBys, input) { ... }
```

It should return a nested object that has child properties of `groupBys[0]`, grandchild properties of `groupBys[1]`, grand grandchildren properties of `groupBys[2]` and so on. The last grand child property has as value an array of objects that belong to this group path (see `expected` output at the bottom).

**I explain the desired behaviour with an example:**

My input is an array of objects. In this example all objects have a property `g1`, `g2` and `g3`.

```
const input = [
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2a', g3: true },
  { g1: 'g1b', g2: 'g2b', g3: 42 },
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2a', g3: 'text' },
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2a', g3: false },
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', g3: 0 },
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', g3: 1 },
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', g3: true },
];
```

In my example, my group functions are:

```
const groupBys = [
  R.prop('g1'),
  R.prop('g2'),
  R.compose(R.type, R.prop('g3'))
];
```

I call `groupByMult` like this

```
const outpout = groupByMult(groupBys, input);
```

And I expect `output` to deeply equal `expected`:

```
const expected = {
  g1a: {
    g2a: {
      Boolean: [
        { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2a', g3: true },
        { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2a', g3: false },
      ],
      String: [
        { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2a', g3: 'text' },
      ],
    },
    g2b: {
      Number: [
        { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', g3: 0 },
        { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', g3: 1 },
      ],
      Boolean: [
        { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', g3: true },
      ],
    },
  },
  g1b: {
    g2b: {
      Number: [
        { g1: 'g1b', g2: 'g2b', g3: 42 },
      ]
    },
  },
}
```

`output` or respectively `expected` has child properties `g1a`, `g1b`, etc. of `groupBys[0]`, grandchild properties `g2a`, `g2b`, etc. of `groupBys[1]`, grand grandchildren properties `Boolean`, `Number` or `String` of `groupBys[2]`, which have an array of objects that belong to this group path. For example, all objects of the array `output.g1a.g2b.Boolean` look like `{ g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', Boolean: <boolean> }` where `<boolean>` represents any boolean value.

How can I implement `groupByMult` to get the described behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be possible via a function that recursively maps over the resulting object values after applying `R.groupBy`.

```
groupByMany = R.curry((fns, items) => 
  R.isEmpty(fns) ? items
                 : R.map(groupByMany(R.tail(fns)),
                         R.groupBy(R.head(fns), items)));
```

This function will take a list of grouping functions along with a list of objects and continue calling itself recursively until there are no more functions to group by.

For example:

```
input = [
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2a', g3: 'g3a' },
  { g1: 'g1b', g2: 'g2c', g3: 'g3d' },
  { g1: 'g1c', g2: 'g2a', g3: 'g3b' },
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', g3: 'g3a' },
  { g1: 'g1a', g2: 'g2b', g3: 'g3b' }
];

groupByMany([R.prop('g1'), R.prop('g2'), R.prop('g3')], input);
```

Results in something like:

```
{ "g1a": { "g2a": { "g3a": [{ "g1": "g1a", "g2": "g2a", "g3": "g3a" }] },
           "g2b": { "g3a": [{ "g1": "g1a", "g2": "g2b", "g3": "g3a" }], 
                    "g3b": [{ "g1": "g1a", "g2": "g2b", "g3": "g3b" }] } },
  "g1b": { "g2c": { "g3d": [{ "g1": "g1b", "g2": "g2c", "g3": "g3d" }] } },
  "g1c": { "g2a": { "g3b": [{ "g1": "g1c", "g2": "g2a", "g3": "g3b" }] } } }
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know ramda and coded the same recursive logic using ifs and fors. It's much longer and not functionnal at all.

Comment: Thanks, but my desired function should take an array of any function that can be passed to [groupBy](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.0/docs/#groupBy). `R.prop` was just a special case. I rewrote the example/description to be more clear.

Comment: @MegaMuetzenMike I've updated the example to pass through functions rather than property names.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't see this before creating mine.  A nice solution.

Comment: More declarative way!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that what you want to do, for your example is something like this:

```
const groups = R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.prop('g1')),
  R.map(R.groupBy(R.prop('g2'))),
  R.map(R.map(R.groupBy(R.compose(R.type, R.prop('g3')))))
);
```

based on an input like this:

```
[
  R.prop('g1'),
  R.prop('g2'),
  R.compose(R.type, R.prop('g3'))
]
```

There is no difficulty wrapping each function in the list with a `groupBy`.  That's just a `map` call.  But there is some work involved in making that increasing list of `map`s for each element.  I'm not sure if there's something more elegant -- or something more efficient -- than this recursive `addMap` helper, but this is what I came up with:

```
const groupByMults = (() => {
  const addMap = fns => fns.length < 1 ? [] : 
      [R.head(fns)].concat(addMap(R.map(R.map, R.tail(fns))));

  return R.curry((groupers, obj) => {
    var fns = addMap(R.map(R.groupBy, groupers))
    return R.apply(R.pipe)(fns)(obj);
  });
}());
```

You can see this in action on **[the Ramda REPL](http://bit.ly/1Q0Pwvt)**

Comment: Yes, there is something more elegant, as [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34722172/1243641) from Scott Christopher shows.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce array of functions and accumulate a mapped composition. For nested grouped object we use map(map(fn), input) to group values again:

```
const groupByMult = R.curry(function(fns, input) {
  const groupByMultReduced = R.reduce(function(acc, fn) {
    if (acc === null) {
      return {
        fn: R.groupBy(fn),
        map: R.map
      };
    }

    return {
      // main function
      fn: R.compose(acc.map(R.groupBy(fn)), acc.fn), 

      // accumulating helper map(map(map(...
      map: R.compose(R.map, acc.map)
    };
  }, null, fns);

  return groupByMultReduced !== null ? groupByMultReduced.fn(input) :  input;
});

let output = groupByMult(groupBys, input);
```

Comment: Thanks, but my desired function should take an array of any function that can be passed to [groupBy](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.0/docs/#groupBy). `R.prop` was just a special case. I rewrote the example/description to be more clear.

Comment: If I [run the example code with your implementation](http://jsbin.com/moberupohu/1/edit?js,console)  a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` is thrown.

Comment: @MegaMuetzenMike fixed, forgot about grouping after changes http://jsbin.com/sohucoqesi/1/edit?js,console